# What if the Alexander's Graham Bell's photophone (LIFI) had been a complete success?

Tags: internal-consistency, alternate-history

What if the Alexander's Graham Bell's photophone (LIFI) had been a complete success?  Would we had advanced quicker in the world with LiFi instead of focus on WiFi?  I am trying to do a what if research paper what do you think the world be like today?

Comment: "What if" as in "What if physics of our world was different?" or as in "What if LED was invented much earlier?"

Comment: This is incredibly broad, and I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with your subject matter to be able to aid in narrowing down your question to something within the scope of this site.

Comment: If you take the time to write up a potential timeline for LiFi discoveries, we could help you determine if it were realistic.  That would narrow the question down enough to fit the site IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Although this answer defers to JBH's excellent answer, it does add a few minor points.

[image]

> Although the photophone was an extremely important invention, the
>   significance of Bell's work was not fully recognized in its time. This
>   was largely due to practical limitations in the technology of the
>   time: Bell's original photophone failed to protect transmissions from
>   outside interferences, such as clouds, that easily disrupted
>   transport.
>
> That changed nearly a century later when the invention of fiber optics
>   in the 1970s allowed for the secure transport of light. Indeed, Bell's
>   photophone is recognized as the progenitor of the modern fiber optic
>   telecommunications system that is widely used to transmit telephone,
>   cable, and internet signals across large distances.

Source: Alexander Graham bell's Photophone

With hindsight we can see the Bell photophone required technological unavailable in the nineteenth century had it been successful its major limitation was line of sight communication. The telephone used wires that can be laid without any consideration of geographical positions of communicating parties. It wasn't limited to line of sight communication. Paradoxically Bell's photophone was over taken by his telephone.

However, if we assume the Bell photophone had been a more effective communications system than proved the case historically, the world that might have resulted would have been one with a more mixed variety of communications systems; telephones, photophones and wireless radio. Depending on economies of scale and ease of operations, these competing technologies would have risen and fallen in their dominance of communications media.

One possible result could have been a faster adoption of fibre optics technology. One caveat with this is what were the developments necessary for its development in terms of glass technology and materials science.

Had the Bell photophone been successful, the history of communications technologies could have been more complicated and diverse.

Answer (score 2):

Vickie, Bell's photophone was a complete success (from a certain point of view), but not in his lifetime.  Focused-beam data transmission (for example, focused microwave data transmission) was around as early as 1899.  Bell's telephone patent was issued only 23 years earlier, in 1876.

But, for the sake of argument, had it become a successful actuality, would it have changed WiFi?  No, it would not.  The biggest limitation of focused-beam data transmission is that you are stuck with point-to-point transmission.  The moment you pick up your "LiFi" laptop and move to the other end of the table, you've broken the connection without going to the router and refocusing the antenna/transmitter.

Focused-beam transmission is very useful for "trunk lines," where you're trying to move a lot of information from one specific point to another specific point over a long distance.  Such transmission doesn't benefit from the mobility of WiFi and so focuses on the energy efficiency of focused transmission.  There are limited options for using that technology today for connecting your house (or a school, or a store) through microwave for satellite-based radio, but that's because they're geographically fixed points (even the satellites, which are in geosynchronous orbit).  While many businesses use this technology, almost no residence does due to its cost.

Therefore, while a few technologies (like your local Chevron gas station's communication back to headquarters) would have advanced just a bit faster, and maybe there'd be a few more residences using LiFi housetop connections to our ISPs rather than cable or DSL connections (there's still the cost issue!), there would ultimately have been no historical impact of Bell's photophone having been a critical success.  We would all still be using WiFi with out phones, pads, and computers.

> It's worth pointing out that no single technology, whether realized earlier or never existing, can have a substantial influence on history.  This is because technology is an ever-expanding pyramid.  Today's single item is the result of an unimaginable number of ideas and inventions in the past.  Even the removal of an individual, Mr. Bell for example, would have no lasting effect as there are always others looking into the same basic technologies.

Comment: Excellent answer! The final quotation about expanding technology and its impact really clinches the possible influence of one invention globally. Please can you give a citation for its source. Plus one.

Comment: @a4android, there isn't a citation.  I'm the source.

Comment: @jbh If its your own words, it shouldn't be in a quote block.

Comment: @T.J.L. People frequently (even most of the time) use "block quote" for emphasis other than approbation on every SE site.  No offence, but the site operation is no where near that ridged.  If my use of the pretty background to highlight my principle conclusion is the worst thing about my post, I'm doing great and will sleep well tonight.  A quote by another person is defined by attribution, not the color behind the text.